# Systems-Modeler returns comple error code 2 when building

Tags: warning-messages, system-modeler

I've been trying to get Systems-Molder to work of a few weeks now for a school project. I can make the models fine however when I try to run the simulation I get the following build errors:

Building "IntroductoryExamples.HelloWorld" as experiment "HelloWorld 1" started at 15:41:00 
[:0:0-0:0] Error: Compilation of generated code failed (exit code 2). Build log:

"Calling Visual C++ setup script "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=x86"

---

** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0.26730.16 
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

---

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.11.25508.2 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'sme.5.0.0_1516221660_24464.makefile' not found 
Stop.
Build finished at 15:41:03 (took 00:02).
Error: No executable generated C:/Users/alexj/AppData/Local/Temp/WolframSystemModeler-5.0.0/sme.5.0.0_1516221660_24464.exe

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask [HERE](http://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=system%20modeler), some developers hang out there.

Answer (score 2):

An update in Visual Studio 2017 broke the interaction between it and SystemModeler 5.0.

You can either upgrade to SystemModeler 5.1, or install Visual Studio 2015 as a workaround.

If you go into `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Compiler`, and press the `Check for Compiler` button, it should suggest and help you with installing the correct configuration of Visual Studio 2015.